How to apply different animation on different element in one useEffect hook?
**I want to aplly separate animation for specific element.When targeting one elemnt by selector only that element is being applied framer property. But dont know how to apply.Kindly resolve my problem, if anyone knows that solution. **
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles/Intro.css";
import { easeIn, useAnimate, useInView } from "framer-motion";

const Intro = () => {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
  const isInView = useInView(scope);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInView) {
      animate(
        ".p1",
        { x: 0 },
        { duration: 1, delay: 1 },
        { Transition: easeIn }
      );
    } else {
      animate(".p1", { x: -300 });
    }
  }, [isInView]);

  return (
    <div className="intro">
      <div className="row">
        <h4 className="text-center mb-4 font-weight-bold">
          BOOK THEBANDWALA FOR YOUR SPECIAL EVENTS
        </h4>
        <p>
          We provide the trusted service, our service is value for money. Anyone
          can book online, we do not charge any extra amount by our customers.We
          provide quality service as per our rates and never compromise to our
          quality. Search and find best service as per your requirement, we have
          a wide range of rates and quality that will fit your specific need.
        </p>

        <div ref={scope} className="row ">
          <div className="card col-md-3 p1">
            <h4 className="mt-4 text-center"> Value for Money</h4>
            <p>
              We do not work for profit only, if our customers are not
              satisfied, then we havent going on to complete our vision. We take
              money for to give satisfaction to our valuable customers, for that
              we offer the value in terms or our service, so that we recall in
              future by our customers.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>

